# Why viewpager2 display same images repeatedly after 5 images from a list.why?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

**I am creating a image and video slider using viewpager2. I used recyclerviewadapter for this. My code is below. The bitmaps from file loaded to imageview correctly.My list has 14 items(images and videos). but linearlayout.addview shows repeated images only. after showing 5 images, it start from 1. Why those images are repeating..please help..My recylerview adapter class is given below..Whats wrong with this**

```
 public SlideViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_slidescreen, parent, false);
        return new SlideViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SlideViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("CHKck", position + " " + getItemCount());
        StatusModel statusModel = itemList.get(position);
        File file = statusModel.getFile();
        Log.d("CHKfileadapt", String.valueOf(file) + " " + position);
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (statusModel.isVideo) {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
                linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                VideoView videoView = new VideoView(context);
                videoView.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(context));
                holder.linearLayout.addView(videoView);


            } else {
                Log.d("CHK", "image");
                holder.linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                holder.linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(statusModel.getPath());
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                holder.linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            }
        }
    }

 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }


    public class SlideViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private LinearLayout linearLayout;
        private List<Integer> poslist = new ArrayList<>();
        private int i = 0;

        public SlideViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llout_slidescreenId);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.AF..I got answer from here...Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you keep adding view inside `onBindViewHolder()` and never removed the removed the previous one. The reason behind this is `RecyclerView.Adapter` reuses the same view holder repeatedly.  Write this as first line inside `onBindViewHolder()`

```
holder.linearLayout.removeAllViews()
```

**NOTE-** You should make few modification to your adapter code .

1. Do not create view at runtime Since there are only 2 views `VideoView` and `ImageView` . have them added in `R.layout.layout_slidescreen` and Change their Visibility accordingly.
2. Do not use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` directly inside `bind` it should be called from a background thread. This will make your UI laggy. Use Some ImageLoader lib `Glide` maybe.

Comment: How i can express my gratitude...Mr.ADM...You are super...Thank you very much...love...

Comment: Sir, I have followed your advice. I added the views to the layout...images and videos are loading now..but during sliding, only few mp4 video files are appearing..but while selecting from a near view or by direct selection, videos are working properly..what will be wrong..please help..